# What is the community URL in the SAML assertion POST?

Tags: community, saml

In this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_auth_configure_saml.htm) says:

"Also make sure that the community URL in the SAML assertion POST includes /login"

Please, tell me what this means. Also. how can I do to verify this condition.
Thanks
Jose

Answer (score 0):

I believe what it means is that the Assertion coming back from your IDP/SSO solution needs to include the /login in the URL. IE don't just add your my domain into your IDP and think its going to work. You must also include the /login at the end. If you really want to test it you could change the domain in your IDP to something stupid www.doesntexist9999.com then when the browser tries to redirect to Salesforce to www.doesntexist9999.com/login  it will fail buy you will be able to see the url in your browser and see the /login with the assertion details etc.

If you have multiple SSO's in the org you will also need to specify the ID of the correct one so that when the assertion comes back to Salesforce, Salesforce knows which org its for (your my domain) and which Single Sign On settings to use (the sso salesforce id). Although I have had a communities SSO and Salesforce user login SSO running fine without the need for a SSO Salesforce Id as the domains were different.